# meteorjs reactjs action after authentification

Tags: meteor, reactjs, onload, account

I have the following react component that passed data to another component:

```
export default class App extends TrackerReact(Component){

 getUserFrameData(){
   return (FrameCollection.find().fetch());
 }
 render(){
   return(
     <div className="main-container">
      <Frames
        data={this.getUserFrameData()}
       />
</div>
);
}
}
```

Now I want my frames component to do an action when the component initialises.

```
export default class Frames extends Component{
   componentDidMount(){
      console.log(this.props.data);
   }

   render() {...}

  }
```

But on I only get empty data at on loadup. I think it's because I'm using subscriptions and a login system. So how can I tell my Frames component to wait until everything is "loaded up"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`ready`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Subscription-ready) method of the subscription object.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    sub: Meteor.subscribe('myPublication')
  }
}

render() {
  if (!this.state.sub.ready()) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  return ...
}
```

http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Subscription-ready